# Issue related to Variable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have some value related to Particular Name, for e.g.:

```
FirstName : Ghanshyam;
LastName : Thakkar;
Age : 25;
Designation : Student;
```

I want to pass this value to another Page using Session. How can I pass both `Name and Value` both in one variable using Session?

Comment: what if you go for JSON / XML ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a 'Person' class, fill that and add to Session.

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName{get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
   public string Designation {get;set;}
}
```

usage:

```
Person thePerson = new Person();
thePerson.FirstName = "Ghanshyam";
thePerson.LastName = "Thakkar";
thePerson.Age = 25;
thePerson.Designation = Student;

Session["ThePerson"] = thePerson;
```

And in the other page:

```
Person thePerson = (Person)Session["ThePerson"];
```

Comment: -1 for the fact that if you don't mark the class as [Serializable you cannot store if to session.

Comment: @Floradu88 - If it's an InProc Session, it will still work, but I'll add it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx ?

This one is good too : http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

As for sending them in one variable : use [Serializable] class and put properties for all the info you need to be passed and store that object in session.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..
Initialize session by

```
Session["value"] = FirstName +":"+LastName ;
```

on the other side of page use split

```
var sessionvalue = Session["value"].toString().Split(':');
```

finally refer using

```
sessionvalue[0],sessionvalue[1]
```

Comment: You should better use defensive programming to get that object and cast your session object to string , after checking it's type.

Comment: yes @Floradu88 u are right too... but even this works in simple case when without classes ...